# Django-facebook authentication

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

I believe i have managed to integrate Django-facebook, but it only logs in the first time. Do you guys have any idea what the problem might?

Comment: Please include all the relevant information which might be required to answer your question. This includes, but is not limited to: what exactly happens when you try logging in for the second time, if you receive any error message, what is it.